# Getting Dynamic Range From Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I tried to do things like this:

```
=SUM(C3:ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))
```

But it didn't work. How can I do it?
(I think there must be a same or very similar question but I'm unable to find it while I searched many times)

Answer (score 0):

for one column:

```
=SUM(C3:C)
```

for two columns:

```
=SUM(C3:D)
```

for all columns:

```
=SUM(C3:CCC)
```

Answer (score 0):

@playerO's answer will work if you want to sum all values in the column/columns/ but if this is a formula you are wanting to fill down along column C to give you a cumulative sum of column C values then the formula would be the following:

```
=SUM(C$3:C3)
```